# Converting elevation between NAD27 and NAD83

Tags: coordinate-system, elevation, wgs84, nad83, nad27

I am working with a large dataset which has datum in NAD27 and NAD83. I needed to convert the northing and easting coordinates with the NAD27 datum to NAD83 datum using Geopandas, which I was able to do successfully. However, many of the measured land surface elevations for the NAD27 data points are way off when we put the data into our LeapFrog model.

I do not have a strong background in GIS, however as the resident computer programmer/engineer for my group I have been thrust into this role for the time being on this project.

From my understanding, NAD27 and NAD83 are 2-D coordinate reference systems. I have read about some ellipsoidal NAD83 which can be used to calculate vertical elevation, but I don't know if any ellipsoidal datums exists for NAD27.

The database also has latitude/longitudes available in WGS 84 coordinate system which I believe is an ellipsoid.

Is there a way to estimate the elevation of the latitudes and longitudes using the WGS 84 ellipsoid system?

I am in over my head a bit with this problem and am having trouble locating appropriate references and reading to understand this problem.

Comment: Easiest way is to use [>>>NCAT<<<](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/).

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a program called "Corps Con". It can help you quite a bit. Corp of engineers published and it is free.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).